# Can avconv or ffmpeg transpose without transcoding?

Tags: ffmpeg

I ran :

```
    avconv -i ./IMG_0271.MOV -vf transpose=1  output.mkv

    ls -al 

   -rw-rw-r--  1 max max  3207681 Mar 26 15:58 IMG_0271.MOV
   -rw-rw-r--  1 max max  1403200 Mar 26 17:10 output.mkv
```

from the difference in sizes of the input and output file I conclude that 
there is transcoding going on, can I avoid this ?

Comment: You can use `ffplay` to transpose upon playback: `ffplay input.mov -vf transpose=1`, or if it's a metadata issue, such as a video from an iPhone, see [An .mov video that is upside down in Windows appears right side up in OSX](http://superuser.com/a/571078/110524). Otherwise, yes, you will have to re-encode to transpose (rotate).